# Reverse for ' signup' not found. ' signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I newbie to Django and I do not know how to fix this problem. I have watched many utube videos to fix this issue, but I found not a single solution.

**Urls.py for project: amazonbackend**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(('Homepage.urls', 'Homepage'))), 
    path('blog/', include(('blog.urls', 'blog'))), 
   

]
```

**urls.py for first app "Homepage"**

```
from django.urls import path
from Homepage import views
urlpatterns = [
 
    path('',views.HomePage,name='Home'),
    path('signup/',views.SignupPage,name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.LoginPage,name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.LogoutPage,name='logout'),
]
```

**urls.py for second app "blog"**

```
from django.urls import path
from blog import views    
urlpatterns = [
 
    path('',views.BlogHomePage,name='bloghome'),
    path('createposts/',views.CreatePosts,name='createposts'),
    path('myposts/',views.MyPosts,name='myposts'),
    path('comments/', views.PostsComments, name= "comments")
]
```

**navbar.html is a template in first app "Homepage"**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 
    <title>Amazon.com Spend less & Smile More</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="AMZN-e9f942e4.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5ac1140461.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav-bar" id="Navigation">
        <div class="nav-box1 box"></div>
        <div class="nav-box2 box">
          <div class="box2-left">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot fa-xl" style="color: #ffffff"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="box2-right">
            <p class="first-box2">Deliver to</p>
            <p class="second-box2">india</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-box3">
          <select name="" id="" class="nav-select">
            <option value="">All</option>
          </select>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search Amazon" class="nav-input">
          <div class="box3-icon">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass fa-xl" style="color: #000000;"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-box4 box">
          <img src=" {% static '/images/1200px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.webp' %}" alt="">
          <select name="" id="" class="box4-select">
            <option value="">EN</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-box5 box">
         <!-- <p class="box-first">Hello,sign in</p> -->
         <a href="{% url 'Homepage: signup' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: small; " > Create Account </a>
          <p class="box-second">Accounts & Lists</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-box6 box">
          <p class="box-first">Return</p>
          <p class="box-second">& Orders</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-box7 box">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-plus fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          <p>Cart</p>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-left box">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
          <p>All</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-middle">
          <p class="box">Today's deal</p>
          <p class="box">Customer Service</p>
          <p class="box">Registry</p>
          <p class="box">Gift card</p>
          <p class="box">Sell</p>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-right box">
          <p>Shop deals in Electronics</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    {% block main %}
    {%endblock%}
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="top">
          <a href="#Navigation">Back to Top</a>
        </div>
        <div class="customer-footer">
          <div class="cust1">
            <p class="cust-first">Get to Know Us</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Career</p>
    
            <p class="cust-Second">About Amazon</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Investor Relations</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Devices</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Science</p>
    
          </div>
          <div class="cust1">
            <p class="cust-first">Get to Know Us</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Career</p><br>
            <a href="{% url 'blog:bloghome' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Blog </a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="{% url 'Homepage: signup' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Sign-Up </a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="{% url 'Homepage: login' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Log-In </a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="{% url 'Homepage: logout' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Log Out </a>
            <br><br>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Science</p>
    
          </div>
          <div class="cust1">
            <p class="cust-first">Get to Know Us</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Career</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Blog</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">About Amazon</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Investor Relations</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Devices</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Science</p>
    
          </div>
          <div class="cust1">
            <p class="cust-first">Get to Know Us</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Career</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Blog</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">About Amazon</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Investor Relations</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Devices</p>
            <p class="cust-Second">Amazon Science</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**List of Lines That are causing error are:**

```
<a href="{% url 'Homepage: signup' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: small; " > Create Account </a>

 <a href="{% url 'blog:bloghome' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Blog </a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="{% url 'Homepage: signup' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Sign-Up </a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="{% url 'Homepage: login' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Log-In </a>
                <br><br>
                <a href="{% url 'Homepage: logout' %}" style= "color:white; font-size: medium; " > Log Out </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no space between the app name and the view name, so:

```
{% url 'Homepage:signup' %}
```

without a space after the colon (`:`).

Comment: Thankyou. Problem is solved